# Entity Framework want to dynamically pass in assembly at startup

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using domain-driven design and need to dynamically build the `DbContext` as the assemblies for my modelbuilders can be in different places depending on the micro service that's reaching for them at the time.

I am using something simple like this

```
services.AddDbContext<PlDbContext>(options =>
            {
                options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
            });
```

Then I have something like this

```
public class PlDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public PlDbContext(DbContextOptions<PlDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

What I want though, is to be able to pass through an assembly.

Basically many of the models/maps live in a class library that sits somewhere else and is shared by a few services. So I just want to be able to say "Go get all the assemblies from there" and apply them on startup.

I know you can do like

```
typeOf(Yada).Assembly
```

there, but I need to be able to pass the assembly through on startup if it's possible, as each service may need a specific subset.

Comment: Pass a System.Type- Assembly isn’t far

Comment: Yeah my question is more along the lines of, how do I pass it to this thing?  I don't see any overloads anywhere for any of this.  Sorry I'm coming from NHibernate and am probably just missing something easy somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure as I haven't checked the code, but won't such a construction work?

```
public class PlDbContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    private readonly Assembly _configurationAssembly;

    public PlDbContext(DbContextOptions<PlDbContext> options, Assembly configurationAssembly)
        : base(options)
    {
        _configurationAssembly = configurationAssembly;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(_configurationAssembly);
    }
}
```

and for the DI you do the following:

```
var configurationAssembly = typeof(SomeTypeFromYourDesiredAssembly).Assembly;

services.AddDbContext<PlDbContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
}, ServiceLifetime.Scoped, ServiceLifetime.Scoped);

services.AddScoped<Assembly>(_ => configurationAssembly);
```

As far as I remember EF uses DI so this one may work for you.

if this registration of PlDbContext won't work, you may think about combining that with the following as well:

```
services.AddTransient<PlDbContext>(provider =>
{
    var options = provider.GetService<DbContextOptions<PlDbContext>>();
    var configurationAssembly = typeof(SomeTypeFromYourDesiredAssembly).Assembly; //you may use some factory here or whatever

    return new PlDbContext(options, configurationAssembly);
});
```

Hope this helps somehow.